# Call a function from a different swift file

Tags: swift, skscene

XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

The first SKScene class in Functions.swift included the *buildBackground* function which I want to call in different SKScene class.

```
class Functions: SKScene {
    
    func buildBackground(backgroundPath: String){
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: backgroundPath)
        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        background.size = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background.name = "BACKGROUND"
        addChild(background)
        print("Background loaded")
    }
    
}
```

I'm trying to call this function in the second SKScene class in the Room.swift file

I created an instance of *Functions* in Room and called my function just like that:

```
    public class Room: SKScene {
    
    let functions = Functions()

    override public func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  
        functions.buildBackground(backgroundPath: "roomBackground")
    }
}
```

I got "**Cannot find 'Functions' in scope**" on the "let functions = Functions()" line. After running a build, I got my message "Background loaded", so I guess, the function was called, however, my wallpaper SKSpriteNode has not appeared in my scene. After I tried to move buildBackground method inside Room.swift class, it all works, but there are a lot of different scenes in my project (Room1, Room2, etc.) so I don't want to copy-paste this method each file.

Comment: Create a base SKScene file.  And inherit it whenever you need an SKScene and use the build background function.

Answer (score 0):

since you are overriding a public function, you probably need to use `self` :

`self.functions.buildBackground(...)`

Comment: I tried but got the same result. buildBackground function called but SKnode is not appearing on the scene.